# How do I save the value of a variable on each loop so I can use those values later

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I'm a complete beginner so excuse my lack of knowledge.

I have a code that is executed several times and the value of a variable is given by the user through prompt. Is there a way to store this value on each loop and display it when the loop ends. Is there a certain element I should use?

Thank you.

```
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
var ngs = 9;
var guess = prompt("what's your guess?");

while (ngs > 0) {
  if (guess < ran) {
    var guess = prompt("nope, that was too low. you have " + ngs + " attempts left. guess again");
    ngs = ngs - 1;
  } else if (guess > ran) {
    var guess = prompt("nope, that was too high. you have " + ngs + " attempts left. guess again.");
    ngs = ngs - 1;
  } else if (guess == ran) {
    alert("gj. you win. your guesses were: ");
  }
}
alert("no more attempts. you lose. your guesses were: ");
```

I need the alerts in the end to display what guesses has the user made.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The basic information we need when you ask a question is: code(what you've tried), an explanation of what you're trying to do/any errors or problems you're running into, and an expected outcome

Comment: Push it into an array? Write it to a string? Many options, all depends on the outcome. Maybe if you showed what you have currently, people could help you out better.

Comment: They're call "variables". Would you like us to recommend a basic javascript tutorial?

Comment: I added the code. I know this is a disaster but please bare with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

epascarello is correct in the comment above. I personally would recommend writing it to a string, but pushing to an array could work just as well.

#### String Method

```
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
var ngs = 9;
var guess = prompt("what's your guess?");
var guesses = ""

while (ngs > 0) {
  if (guess < ran) {
    var guess = prompt("nope, that was too low. you have " + ngs + " attempts left. guess again");
    ngs = ngs - 1;
    guesses += guess + ' ';
  } else if (guess > ran) {
    var guess = prompt("nope, that was too high. you have " + ngs + " attempts left. guess again.");
    ngs = ngs - 1;
    guesses += guess + ' ';
  } else if (guess == ran) {
    alert("gj. you win. your guesses were: " + guesses);
  }
}
alert("no more attempts. you lose. your guesses were: " + guesses);
```

#### Array Method

```
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
var ngs = 9;
var guess = prompt("what's your guess?");
var guesses = []

while (ngs > 0) {
  if (guess < ran) {
    var guess = prompt("nope, that was too low. you have " + ngs + " attempts left. guess again");
    ngs = ngs - 1;
    guesses.push(guess);
  } else if (guess > ran) {
    var guess = prompt("nope, that was too high. you have " + ngs + " attempts left. guess again.");
    ngs = ngs - 1;
    guesses.push(guess);
  } else if (guess == ran) {
    alert("gj. you win. your guesses were: " + guesses.join(' '));
  }
}
alert("no more attempts. you lose. your guesses were: " + guesses.join(' '));
```

Comment: You have `enter code here` embedded in your samples, and your `alert` function calls are missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the redeclaration of the guess variable within the if/else. Secondly you can take a look at the following link for description of the Array class. 
[Javascript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a second to read the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page. Notably, please `quote the most relevant part of an important link` and note that a full explanation is more useful.